# ModelValidationException jersey custom object

Tags: java, angularjs, jersey, jackson

I'm building an application with angularjs, jersey and Jackson.

My angularjs method :

```
services.factory('newDBFactory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/easyshow/api/folders/angu/:scannedShows', {}, {
    save: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {scannedShows : '@scannedShows'},
        isArray: true
    }
})
```

});

is supposed to call my jersey method :

```
@POST
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/angu/{scannedShows}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testAngu(@PathParam("scannedShows") List<ScannedShow> scannedShows) {
    return "YEAH";
}
```

But when i try to run as debug my application, there is an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
```

Here are my objects : ScanedShow

```
package com.businessLogic;
```

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ScannedShow {

```
public ScannedShow() {
}

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("properties")
private ShowProperties properties;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ShowProperties getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(ShowProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}
}
```

And ShowProperties :

```
public class ShowProperties {

public ShowProperties(){
}

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;

@JsonProperty("seriesName")
private String seriesName;

@JsonProperty("firstAired")
private String firstAired;

@JsonProperty("overview")
private String overview;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSeriesName() {
    return seriesName;
}
public void setSeriesName(String seriesName) {
    this.seriesName = seriesName;
}
public String getFirstAired() {
    return firstAired;
}
public void setFirstAired(String firstAired) {
    this.firstAired = firstAired;
}
public String getOverview() {
    return overview;
}
public void setOverview(String overview) {
    this.overview = overview;
}
}
```

Comment: The `List<ScannedShow>` method parameter is the problem. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the actual value of `{scannedShows}`, that you think it's a good idea to represent it as a `List<ScannedShow>`? Maybe instead you mean to pass the data as the _body_ of the request instead of in the URL?

Comment: I pass an array of 2 scannedShow from my web pages to store them in a database. So i thought it was a good idea to use a list. I don't know how to pass parameters execpt with this method.

Comment: If you just want the _path_ parameter to be a single value, and _body_ of the request to be the list, then you should do something more like `@PathParam("scannedShows") String pathParam,  List<ScannedShow> body)`. The method parameter with no annotations will we the request body

Comment: Ok but there is probably some changes with the angular method, no ?